# Como validar un dropdown list de asp.net sea mayor a cero con jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hola comunidad  necesito validar si un dropdownlist de asp.net con jquery si este no se a seleccionado ningun item. Alguien podría ayudarme. Tengo esto pero no funciona.

```js
var Esquema = $('select[name=ddlEsquema]').val()
if ( Esquema > 0) { hacer algo }
else
        alert("Por favor seleccione datos);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando renderizas un dropdown en asp.net el código que se genera para el browser es algo como esto:

```
<select name="ddlEsquema">
    <option value="">Etiqueta por defecto</option>
    <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
</select>
```

Si el usuario selecciona una opción en el dropdown, jquery te devuelve el atributo `value` de la opción seleccionada. En caso de que no se seleccione ninguna opción el método `.val()` te devuelve `""` (que es una cadena vacía). Usando esto como base puedes entonces implementar tu código para chequear que el valor del dropdown no es vacío.

Algo como esto puede servirte:

```
var Esquema = $('select[name=ddlEsquema]').val();
if ( Esquema !== "") { 
    //hacer algo
}
else
    alert("Por favor seleccione datos);
```

Algo más idiomático en javascript es simplemente usar el hecho de que una cadena vacía es un valor "falsy" en javascript. Eso significa que si pones algo que es vacío en un una condición se evalúa a `false`. Por lo anterior, es suficiente con escribir solamente:

```
var Esquema = $('select[name=ddlEsquema]').val();
if ( Esquema) { //si Esquema es "" esta condición es false. 
    //hacer algo
}
else
    alert("Por favor seleccione datos);
```

En este fiddle puedes ver un ejemplo concreto: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yfpxc5

### Bonus: Truthy and Falsy en Javascript.

Traducido del inglés desde: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Cada valor en javascript tiene un valor booleano inherente, que generalmente se conocen como `truthy` o `falsy`. Algunas de las reglas son bastante raras así que entender los conceptos y su efecto te puede ayudar cuando depuras aplicaciones Javascript.

Los siguientes son siempre falsy:

- false
- 0 (cero)
- '' or "" (cadena vacía)
- null
- undefined
- NaN

Todo lo demás es truthy:

- '0' (una cadena con un solo cero)
- 'false' (una cadena con el texto “false”)
- [] (un arreglo vacío)
- {} (un objeto vacío)
- function(){} (una función vacía)

Espero te sirva.